# Different clock rates near a black hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relativity

We have two TVs on Earth that 2 users watch living in different time zones. For them, the TV shows happen at the same hour, they receive signal from the same source. they agree because their clocks run at the same speed. If user 1 calls user 2 to turn to Channel X, they will be watching the same thing.
Let’s now suppose that one TV is inside the event horizon of a black hole and one is on the outside. Since their clocks run differently, how this changes the delay in TV shows between the two TVs?

Comment: Turns out this depends on the choice of coordinates.

Comment: @AaronStevens Aaron I'd never attach a H-a-E tag to a GR question. Let's be honest: how many people do you believe there are in PSE able to give correct answers to such questions?

Comment: @ElioFabri I don't think "answerability" is mentioned in the tag description. The tag not for perceived level of difficulty. The tag is not meant to trivialize the question. You're probably just associating with the usually bad homework questions asked here, but the tag itself doesn't mean this is a bad question like those